# Spark: clean way to fill nulls based on schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I've got avro files that are formatted like this:

```
|Some col|Some other col|          body         |
|--------|--------------|-----------------------|
|some val|   some val   |   some json string    |
|  ...   |     ...      |         ...           |
```

- I read them using `spark.read.format("avro").load(file_path)`
- I want to select all values from that json string, but this json is trimmed, so only columns where the value isn't None are given.
- I've got a schema that contains all possible values from these json files (all nullable).

> **QUESTION:** is there's a clean way to select all columns from the json string + all columns from the schema that are not in the json string with None as inserted value?

Comment: If I get the question, you want to add those missing columns (dict keys in the example) names into the 'json string'? You could convert the json to dict: `json.loads`, check for the keys and insert missing keys with value 'None'.

Comment: I eventually want to end up with a dataframe with those columns. For that I'd have to place them in a select statement, but selecting none existing columns results in a tuple instead of a dataframe.

Comment: Could you post your first five elements of the `df` maybe?

Comment: The json should become the dataframe. The other values in the avro file can be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
In [1]: from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType
   ...: from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json

In [2]: schema = StructType([
   ...:     StructField("a", StringType()),
   ...:     StructField("b", StringType()),
   ...:     StructField("c", StringType()),
   ...:     StructField("d", StringType()),
   ...: ])

In [3]: df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'),
   ...:                             ("2", '{"a": 3, "c": 4}')],
   ...:                            schema=["Some col", "body"])

In [4]: df.show()
+--------+----------------+
|Some col|            body|
+--------+----------------+
|       1|{"a": 1, "b": 2}|
|       2|{"a": 3, "c": 4}|
+--------+----------------+

In [5]: df.select(from_json(col("body"), schema).alias("data")).select("data.*").show()
+---+----+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|   d|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|   2|null|null|
|  3|null|   4|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: What is the `dtype` of those cols?

Comment: @deponovo the question concerns Spark, not pandas. Columns in my example are all `StringType`. In case OP's JSON contains fields of different types, module `pyspark.sql.functions` contains other types such as `IntegerType`, `ArrayType`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to completely understand the question but it seems a `df` is gotten through `spark.read.format("avro").load(file_path)`. One of the columns in that `df` is `body` and that column is a series of dictionaries. One potential solution is:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

entry_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
entry_2 = {'b': 2, 'c': 2}
entry_3 = {'c': 3, 'd': 3}

df = pd.DataFrame({'body': [entry_1, entry_2, entry_3]})  # 1
series_of_dict_to_df = pd.DataFrame(df.body.to_dict()).T  # 2
df = pd.concat([df, series_of_dict_to_df], axis=1) 

# string version
entry_1 = "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 1}"
entry_2 = "{\"b\": 2, \"c\": 2}"
entry_3 = "{\"c\": 3, \"d\": 3}"

df_with_strings = pd.DataFrame({'body': [entry_1, entry_2, entry_3]})  
df_with_strings.body = df_with_strings.body.map(json.loads)  # 1
series_of_dict_to_df = pd.DataFrame(df_with_strings.body.to_dict()).T  #2
df_with_strings = pd.concat([df_with_strings, series_of_dict_to_df], axis=1)
```

The output for both dataframe versions is:

```
               body    a    b    c    d
0  {'a': 1, 'b': 1}  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  {'b': 2, 'c': 2}  NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN
2  {'c': 3, 'd': 3}  NaN  NaN  3.0  3.0
```

The missing column data get automatically filled with NaN. (Note that the positions marked with `#1` and `#2` in the code are those potentially relevant to solving the prob. The remaining code is for demonstration purposes.